# Class visibility changes after importing another file

Tags: module, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I have an angular2 project with typescript and I am facing a weird behavior that I cannot understand. I have a class file (call it main.ts) that contains a component, so it **has some imports** at the top of the file and I have created a class that represents a custom type somewhere else in the project (let us say models/typeFoo.ts). In typeFoo.ts there is a simple TypeFoo class **with no imports** and somehow the type TypeFoo  can be used in main.ts without the need the file to be imported in main.ts. That is weird? Then **I make an import** of another file in typeFoo.ts and automatically the main.ts complains that TypeFoo in not visible anymore. Can someone explain what is going on here?

```
main.ts
--models/typeFoo.ts

class TypeFoo {
   name:string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> somehow the type TypeFoo can be used in main.ts without the need the file to be imported in main.ts. That is weird

In the absence of a root level `import` or `export` the file is consider a *global* file. Adding an `import` or `export` converts it into a module (a good thing).

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: I have read somewhere that "A file is a module and a module is a file", which meant to me, that creating a file makes it having its own "scope" not visible to the global. But what you say, is different and makes sense. I don't think that this is clearly stated in the documentation of typescript. Thank you!